# Enable JavaScript in URL bar in Firefox

Tags: firefox, javascript

Is there any method in `about:config` to enable in the URL bar JavaScript prefixed by `javascript:` to run in Firefox?

`browser.urlbar.filter.javascript: false` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript: false` doesn't seem to work.

Indeed it doesn't. You can work around it using Bookmarks (at least until Mozilla block that as well):

> - Set up a Bookmark with the location: `javascript:%s`
> - Set the keyword for that bookmark as: `javascript`
>
> Now you can run JavaScript from the address bar in the format:
>   `javascript alert('Hello World')` which is very similar to the old
>   `javascript:alert('Hello World')` method - it's just that the colon
>   needs to be replaced by a space.

Source [Executing JavaScript in Firefox address bar - AutoHotkey Community](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=58269)

Comment: Thak you very much. You saved my day. I've been googling for this many days. I was near a nervous breakdown ;-)

Comment: Nice, you can also add `js` as a keyword to the bookmark, if you want a shorthand.

Comment: It is not explicitly stated, but note that this effectively means that Firefox still supports bookmarklets - it just requires them to be run via an assigned _keyword_ (through address bar), or via clicking on them...

Answer (score 0):

The setting you are trying to use only controls whether javascript: URLs show up as auto completes when you type in the URL Bar.  From http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.filter.javascript

> True
>   Filter out “javascript:” URLs from appearing in the Location Bar autocomplete dropdown. (Default)
>
> False
>   Allow “javascript:” URLs to appear in the dropdown.

It seems javascript: URLs are completely disabled in newer version of firefox.

However you should still be able to save javascript: URLs as bookmarks and activate them by clicking on them.

Other people have noticed this too:

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/9qykd0/firefox_63_disabled_javascript_in_address_bar/